# MongoDB aggregation query to return total number of entries in a collection per year-month, grouped by a location value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm attempting to write a mongo aggregation query that returns the total number of entries in a collection per **year-month**, grouped by a **location**.

Here is an example of the desired output:

```
  [
          {
            _id: 'Location 1',
            reviews: [
              { total: 12, date: '03-2019' },
              { total: 55, date: '04-2019' },
              { total: 9, date: '05-2019' }
            ]
          },
          {
            _id: 'Location 2',
            reviews: [
              { total: 8, date: '03-2019' },
              { total: 35, date: '04-2019' },
              { total: 12, date: '05-2019' }
            ]
          }
        ];
```

This is a truncated example of the schema:

```
  {
    branchId: { type: String, required: true },
    orgId: { type: String, required: true },
    stars: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    reviewUpdatedAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
  }
```

I'm able to return the data in various ways, but having issues getting the desired output. Here are some example queries where I've ran into road blocks. Basically I have issues trying to group the total entries per month, then group that further down by branchId / location.

Here is an example of grouping by the year-month. The response contains the counts per branchId, but the _ids have duplicates for the month-year for each branch. I need the _id to be the location and to have an array containing the total and the year-month as shown in the above example of the desired output.

```
[
      {
        $match: {
            stars: {$exists: true, $gte: 1},
            orgId: '100003'
       //   reviewUpdatedAt: { $gte: new Date(fromDate), $lte: new Date(toDate) }
        }
      },

      {
        $group: {
          _id: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$reviewUpdatedAt' }},
          branchId: {$addToSet: '$branchId'},
          total: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      },
        {
          $unwind: '$branchId'
        },
      { $sort: { _id: 1 } }
    ]
```

In the above example I've had some success adjusting the group and `$unwind` statement like so:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$branchId',
        date: { $addToSet: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m', date: '$reviewUpdatedAt' } } },
        total: { $sum: 1 }
    }
},
{ $unwind: '$date' }
```

However, the total $sum is not accurate and repeats for each branchId entry. How can I modify the above queries to produce the desired output? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        date: {
          $dateToString: {
            format: "%m-%Y",
            date: "$reviewUpdatedAt"
          }
        },
        loc: "$branchId"
      },
      Total: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.loc",
      reviews: {
        $push: {
          Total: "$Total",
          "date": "$_id.date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ufpcBODZ4Fa)

Comment: This works great! However, is it possible to insert an entry for a month that does not have a result? For instance lets say if my $match has a date range of 01-2019 to 12-2019. I would like to have all 12 entries for the month with a default of total: 0. Is this possible ?

Comment: @AndrewTaylor : I would certainly put my answer, but it's a bit tricky to do, can you raise a new question that way it would be clear on it's own way & someone would answer it even if I fail to do so or meanwhile I do that it..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60571986/edit-a-mongo-aggregation-query-to-return-default-result-for-a-grouped-time-perio

Comment: @AndrewTaylor : By any chance do you start on a month in 2018 & end at a month in 2019. Like :: 08-2018 to 09-2019 ?? (or is that just for a specific year like 01-2019 to 12-2019) ?

Comment: Yes, the query could technically be any range of time / period of months. However, by default it will run on the 1st of each month and take the current date and go back 12 months.